# How to call the API key randomly in PHP and send to json

Tags: php, random

Please help, I have 10 API KEYs and I want to call a random "API key":

**This is my code:**

```
$keyword = str_replace(' ', '+' , get_the_title());

$api = api1 , api2 , api3

$jsonfile='domain.com/get.php?q='.$keyword.'&key='.$api.'&format=json';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonfile));
```

but... how do I select a random API? Thanks.

Comment: `array_rand` function

Comment: I made the question here to get answers to my problems. 

thanks for helping to fix the question that I've made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`rand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function:

```
$api_keys = array('key1','key2','key3','key4','key5','key6','key7','key8','key9','key10');

$randKey = rand(0,10);   

$jsonfile='domain.com/get.php?q='.$keyword.'&key='.$api_keys[$randKey].'&format=json';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to achieve what your require.

```
$api = array('api1' , 'api2' , 'api3');
$randomAPI = $api[array_rand($api)];
$jsonfile='domain.com/get.php?q='.$keyword.'&key='.$randomAPI.'&format=json';
```

https://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.array.php